# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request WCF REST

Tags: wcf

I found similar posts, but everything I've tried doesn't work. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? First is my client config and second my server config.
First I thought that it is because I try to receive a large amount of data, but that wasn`t the problem in my case.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:56923/TestService.svc?wsdl"
              behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
              contract="TestService.TestService"
              name="WcfServiceApp.TestService" />
  </client>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBinding" 
               maxBufferSize="2097151"
               maxBufferPoolSize="2097151"
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2097151">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" 
                      maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                      maxArrayLength="16384" 
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

---

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBinding" 
               maxBufferSize="2097151" 
               maxBufferPoolSize="2097151" 
               maxReceivedMessageSize="2097151">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" 
                      maxStringContentLength="2097151"
                      maxArrayLength="16384" 
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                      maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that jumps out is the `<client>` configuration in the client's config, specifically the address attribute.

```
address="http://localhost:56923/TestService.svc?wsdl"
```

First, you said you're using REST, so the WSDL file doesn't play a role in that (it's for SOAP services).

Second, the WSDL file is not the service, it's the **W**eb **S**ervice **D**escription **L**anguage file, which describes the web service so clients can build a proxy to it (again, this is for SOAP, not REST).

Try changing the address in your client config to just the service file:

```
address="http://localhost:56923/TestService.svc"
```

Comment: I changed the address but it still doesn`t work, not I get another one. It tells me: The contract attribute is invalid according to its datatype 'clientcontracttype'. I added the endpoint for client also in service configuration, but I can`t use the same contract in both client and server configuration..